# SSRS - Wrong parameter label after click on "View Report"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I developed a report in which users can convert values from Euro (€) into an other currency.
I created a dataset for the currency parameter which looks like this:

```
ID | symbol | rate
```

ID = identifier, symbol = currency cut off (e.g. EUR, USD, GPD, YEN...), rate = conversion rate

Under Available Values I set "rate" as "Value field" and "symbol" as "Label field".

Under Default Values I set "rate" as "Value field".

Now everything works fine, the parameters shows EUR etc. as labels and the user can convert the values.

**But there is one exception.**

**Two currencies** (PAB and USD) have the **same rate** (1.3256). Now when I try to convert the values in US Dollar and select "USD" in the parameter and click on "View Report", SSRS changes the parameter from USD to PAB. The values are converted correctly because the rate is the same, but I also use the label in my report. So instead of "Amount in USD" the report shows "Amount in PAB".

I have no idea how i can fix this. Is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the parameter to be the ID. Then add an additional, internal parameter that will get the rate value from another dataset which takes the ID as a parameter. Use the internal parameter in your queries.

Comment: That's a nice and simple solution. Thank you! :)